# CONFLICT_FREE_OFFSET macro used in the parallel prefix algorithm from GPU Gems 3

Tags: cuda, prefix-sum

First of all, here is the link to the algorithm:

GPU Gems 3, Chapter 39: [Parallel Prefix Sum (Scan) with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html).

In order to avoid bank conflicts, padding is added to the shared memory array every NUM_BANKS (i.e., 32 for devices of computability 2.x) elements. This is done by (as in Figure 39-5):

```
int ai = offset*(2*thid+1)-1
int bi = offset*(2*thid+2)-1
ai += ai/NUM_BANKS
bi += ai/NUM_BANKS
temp[bi] += temp[ai]
```

I don't understand how ai/NUM_BANKS is equivalent to the macro:

```
   #define NUM_BANKS 16  
   #define LOG_NUM_BANKS 4  
   #define CONFLICT_FREE_OFFSET(n) \  
          ((n) >> NUM_BANKS + (n) >> (2 * LOG_NUM_BANKS))
```

Isn't it equal to

```
n >> LOG_NUM_BANKS
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wrote that code and co-wrote the article, and I request that you use the article only for learning about scan algorithms, and do not use the code in it.  It was written when CUDA was new, and I was new to CUDA.  If you use a modern implementation of scan in CUDA you don't need any bank conflict avoidance.

If you want to do scans the easy way, use [`thrust::inclusive_scan`](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__prefixsums.html) or [`thrust::exclusive_scan`](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__prefixsums.html).

If you really want to implement a scan, refer to more recent articles such as this one [[1]](https://web.archive.org/web/20191004042728/http://www.idav.ucdavis.edu:80/publications/print_pub?pub_id=1041). Or for a real opus with faster code but that will require a bit more study, this one [[2]](https://sites.google.com/site/duanemerrill/ScanTR2.pdf?attredirects=0).  Or read [Sean Baxter's tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20110924131401/http://www.moderngpu.com/intro/scan.html) (though the latter doesn't include citations of the seminal work on the scan algorithm).

[1] Shubhabrata Sengupta, Mark Harris, Michael Garland, and John D. Owens. "Efficient Parallel Scan Algorithms for many-core GPUs". In Jakub Kurzak, David A. Bader, and Jack Dongarra, editors, Scientific Computing with Multicore and Accelerators, Chapman & Hall/CRC Computational Science, chapter 19, pages 413–442. Taylor & Francis, January 2011.

[2] Merrill, D. and Grimshaw, A. Parallel Scan for Stream Architectures. Technical Report CS2009-14, Department of Computer Science, University of Virginia. Dec. 2009.

Comment: I've been doing a bit of research on this as well, and if anyone was interested why, see: G.5.3 in cuda c-programming guide: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-5-x
According to that section, as long as your device has compute capability 5.x or above, two threads accessing the same bank will not generate a bank conflict ( in a simple case as in scan example mentioned in question) , although multiple threads writing will as expected generate un-defined behaviour.